# Linq query with grouping, null values, and many joins

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

My aim is object like this:

- List:

  - Valueid
  - Value
  - List of products that are assignment to above value (all Values can have many products, but some doesn't have any)

**query:**

```
var test = (from values in GetAllValues

                    join productValues in context.ProductValue on values.ValueId equals productValues.ValueId into pv
                    from productValues in pv.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    join products in context.Products on productValues.ProductId equals products.ProductId into p
                    from products in p.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    select new AdminSelectionProductValue()
                    {
                        ValueId = values.ValueId,
                        Value = values.Value,
                        ProductList = p.Select(x=> new P(x.ProductId, x.Name)).ToList(),
                    } into aspv

                    group aspv by aspv.ValueId into g
                    select g
    ).ToList();
```

**helper class:**

```
public class AdminSelectionProductValue
{
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<P> ProductList { get; set; }

    public class P
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public P(int productId, string name)
        {
            this.ProductId = productId;
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm okay with anonymous type.

My result:
[image: My result:]

Please help with Linq query, I'm not good at it.

**SampleData:**

```
+---------+------------------+-------------------+
| ValueId | Value            | ProductList       |
+         +                  +-------------------+
|         |                  | ProductId | Name  |
+---------+------------------+-----------+-------+
| 1       | Wheel            | 1         | 16"   |
+         +                  +-----------+-------+
|         |                  | 2         | 20"   |
+         +                  +-----------+-------+
|         |                  | 3         | 24"   |
+---------+------------------+-----------+-------+
| 2       | Front Derailleur | 8         | Acer  |
+         +                  +-----------+-------+
|         |                  | 9         | Deore |
+---------+------------------+-----------+-------+
| 3       | Color            | null      | null  |
+---------+------------------+-----------+-------+
| 4       | Size             | null      | null  |
+---------+------------------+-----------+-------+
```

**Answer:**
I didnt added post-answer because I didnt manage aim with only linqu.

```
List<AdminSelectionProductValue> listAspv = new List<AdminSelectionProductValue>();
            foreach (var v in GetAllValues)
            {
                var productValues = new EFProductValueRepository(context).GetProductValueByValueId(v.ValueId);

            AdminSelectionProductValue aspv = new AdminSelectionProductValue();
            aspv.Value = v.Value;
            aspv.ValueId = v.ValueId;
            aspv.ProductList = (from pv in productValues join p in context.Products on pv.ProductId equals p.ProductId select new PoductHelper(pv.ProductId, p.Name)).ToList();
            listAspv.Add(aspv);
        }
        return listAspv;
```

Comment: You used left join, so some ProductList has no data.

Comment: and its okey, my aim result is: simple list with value id value and list of product assigment to value, but some value dosent have product so they will have null list. I want to avoid situation like in image when is the same value 'Rama' have for each item separate list with one item

Comment: As I understand, you want to group following Value, right? To more clearly, you can post some sample data, and show expected the result.

Comment: you want to group following Value, right? - yes

Comment: Just modified that line: group aspv by aspv.Value into g. You can visit this link to refer more to Group in Linq: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea